# html.tpl.php is ignored

Tags: 7

I have Drupal 7 site using a custom theme, which was working just fine. I created some regions and then I went and extracted some parts of the `html.tpl.php` file and made them blocks to make them translatable. The idea was to display these new blocks in the new regions. But all of a sudden my theme stopped working and now drupal ignores my html.tpl.php file and uses the default. I have no idea what went wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**: I checked the logs and i noticed this error, just before the problem begun.

```
The directory /var/www/***********/tmp does not exist and could not be created.
```

I have a development server which runs the same site and this directory is specific to that. So i created a `/tmp` directory in the live site and set it in the configuration page but still the problem persists.

**EDIT2**: I am using a `template.php` file to send the blocks to the `html.tpl.php`. Something like this:

```
function <themename>_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['footer_menu'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('footer_menu');
  $variables['info_bar'] = block_get_blocks_by_region('info_bar');
}
```

Comment: I assume you tried to clear cache?

Comment: Yes, i did. It is still the same.

Comment: Did you try changing the theme to say Bartik and then back to your custom theme?

Comment: Check available variables in `html.tpl.php` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7

Comment: Yeah i did change the theme to a contributed one (Bartik is not there). The new theme works but when i change it back to my custom theme, everything is same again.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me, too. With another tpl, but anyway. I opened the file, copied content, deleted file, created new with the same name, pasted content, saved, cleared cache - and it worked. Don't know why or how.

Comment: Thanks @Mołot, but that didn't solve it also.

Comment: @lunr that's why I didn't post it as an answer. This was too "magic"... But no hurt in sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The question is bit confusing and contradicting. The `html.tpl` file is just there to take care of the HTML structure. If you need to add regions or change blocks, then `page.tpl.php` is the one you need to change.

SR

Comment: in `html.tpl.php` you cant print regions.

Comment: @NikhilM - Before you mark my answer down, you should have read it first. All i said was in html.tpl you cant print regions. You also said the same?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in html.tpl.php you can print regions, although there is some extra work to be done. (passing the block to the file as a variable) Apparently this is not common, but before it was working just fine. Do you think this is related to the problem here?

Comment: *"file is just there to pass on the template variables"* - simply false for `html.tpl.php`. It is there to create basic tags needed on all HTML outputs, not just to pass variables. Probably you confused files?